# Can I use 2 counters in one while loop?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have this code which is working as expected without the try part, and get two answers

```
while counter < (len(response['Reservations'])):
    INSTANCEID = response['Reservations'][counter]['Instances'][0]['InstanceId']
    ITYPE = response['Reservations'][counter]['Instances'][0]['InstanceType']
    print('ID: %s, Type: %s') % (INSTANCEID, ITYPE)
    counter += 1
    try:
        IPROFILE = response['Reservations'][counter]['Instances'][***<<2nd counter??>>***]['IamInstanceProfile'][0]['Arn']
        print IPROFILE
        counter += 1
        return IPROFILE
    except:
        print('No ARN found')
```

output:

```
ID: i-abcd123, Type: t2.micro.  
ID: i-defg456, Type: t2.large
```

Once I add the `try` part I get only this answer:

```
ID: i-abcd123, Type: t2.micro.  
ARN: arn:<VERY_LONG_STRING_OF_ARN>
```

Which makes me to believe that the while loop is not iterating as it should.
So this bring me to my questions: can I use 2 'counter' in one sentence ?
Do I need to separate the filter like this (an example, not really working for me)

```
IPROFILE = response['Reservations'][counter]['Instances']
I2PROFILE = IPROFILE[0]['IamInstanceProfile'][0]['Arn']
```

Maybe use another while loop for that other 'counter', beneath the first one?

Comment: i might be wrong.
but looking at your code.
its because you are using that 'return' which return the value and stop the while loop. Just to check, try run with print function. is it still break or not.

Comment: Do you really need two counters? Can't you just use the same counter, but increment it after the `try` block?

Comment: @NMAA thanks, that helped.

Comment: @Barmar Well, that was my question...

Comment: Well, it's not clear what you're trying to do, so it's hard to answer. You're incrementing the counter multiple times for some reason, I don't know why.

Comment: @Barmar the idea was to increment is that in what ever stage it was, it will still so correctly, In any way I found a working solution. thanks for helping out !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I had an error in my filtering,
It turned out I didn't need the 2nd counter, and my +1 counter was misplaced.

My thanks for the responders: you helped me a lot.

This is the working code for generation to come...:

```
counter = 0
while counter < (len(response['Reservations'])):
    INSTANCEID = response['Reservations'][counter]['Instances'][0]['InstanceId']
    ITYPE = response['Reservations'][counter]['Instances'][0]['InstanceType']
    print('ID: %s, Type: %s') % (INSTANCEID, ITYPE)
    try:
        IPROFILE = response['Reservations'][counter]['Instances'][0]['IamInstanceProfile']['Arn']
        print IPROFILE
        print('--')
        counter += 1
        #print counter
    except:
        print('No Role attached - Trying to attach')
        print('--')
        attach_role(INSTANCEID,REGION)
        counter += 1
```

Comment: Why do you increment counter in both `try` and `except`? If you need to do something in both cases, put it after the `try/except` block.

Comment: It's also not clear that you actually need `try`. Better would be `if 'IamInstanceProfile' in response['Reservations'][counter]['Instances'][0]:`

Comment: @Barmar 'IPROFILE ' would give an error if there was no instance profile attached to the Instance, so in order to overcome it I use the try/except. I guess I could have used it with 'if' statement.

Comment: If you know what error you expect, `if` is better. `try` is for unpredictable errors.

Comment: @Barmar Cool , good to know.    I generally use exept like this :    
  
`except ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'NoSuchEntity':
          print("NoSuchEntity")`
Which is a known error, is there another way to use it ?

Answer (score 1):

You code is not very Pythonic. Normally, there should be **no need to use a counter**. I can't see your full code, but it should be more like:

```py
response = client.describe_instances()

for reservation in response['Reservations']:
    for instance in reservation['Instances']:
        instance_type = instance['InstanceType']
        print(instance_type)
```

Comment: I see what you did here, that is interesting.
I will try it, thanks!